# When was "one true" originally used

Tags: etymology

Lately this combination of words have been showing up everywhere.

- One true king.
- One true way to find something
- One true God
- One true Morty

etc. What is the history of this word combination?

Comment: The *substance* (if not the precise *syntax*) of *[the] one true God,* for example, almost certainly predates anything we would recognise as "English" today. What kind of answer are you expecting?

Comment: Are you okay with similar phrases in other languages. Here's a 5th century Latin equivalent of "One True God": https://www.loebclassics.com/view/augustine-city_god_pagans/1957/pb_LCL412.251.xml. I'd be surprised if this is the first.

Answer (score 2):

The dictionaries I checked (OED and MED) did not have examples of "one true" in this sense, so I had to do my own searches. Due to how difficult it is to search for phrases in Middle English I'm pretty sure there are earlier examples I haven't found (since in ME [one](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED30547&egs=all&egdisplay=open) was spelled 30+ different ways and [true](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED46999) was spelled 20+ different ways).

The earliest example I found is from 1485:

> Charles, the noble Emperour, after he had̛ taken moche payne for to mayntene the name of god̛ for tenhaunce the crysten fayth, and to brynge al the world̛ in **one trewe fayth and̛ byleue**, & that he had̛ goten many contrees, he purposed neuer more to fyght ne to make bataylle, but to reste & lede forth a contemplatyf lyf, in thankyng̛ his maker of þe grace that he had̛ gyuen to hym in surmountyng̛ hys enemyes.
>   <sub>[Lyf of the noble and Crysten prynce, Charles the Grete](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/CharlesG/1:6.1?rgn=div2;view=fulltext)</sub>

The next earliest examples I found are from Thomas More in 1533, all from [the same work](http://tei.it.ox.ac.uk/tcp/Texts-HTML/free/A07/A07694.html):

> - one trew catholyke fayth
> - one trewe fayth
> - one trew chyrch of Crist
> - one trewe worde

---

As lbf's answer says, *true* (without "one") in this same sense (i.e. "real, genuine, etc.") was first used in the late 14th century, in this quote from a [translation of *De Proprietatibus Rerum*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/hyp-idx?type=id&id=hyp.1615.19981211T105002) (a1398):

> It is harde..to knowe bitwen þe verry precious stones and fals, for ofte þilke þat ben false and gilefulle semen most liche to hem þat ben **trewe** and verray, so þat vnneþe me may knowe bitwene þe **trewe** and gilefull.

Answer (score 1):

one **true** x,y or z ; etymology thereof:

> Sense of "**consistent with fact**" first recorded c. 1200; that of
>   "**real, genuine, not counterfeit**" is from late 14c.; that of
>   "conformable to a certain standard" (as true north) is from c. 1550.
>   Of artifacts, "accurately fitted or shaped" it is recorded from late
>   15c. True-love (n.) is Old English treowlufu. True-born (adj.) first
>   attested 1590s. True-false (adj.) as a type of test question is
>   recorded from 1923. To come true (of dreams, etc.) is from 1819.

[etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/true)

My sense is that 'one' is self-explanatory and does not need etymological
interpretation nor is it necessary.  But if one desires:  [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/one)

I found no one etymological explanation of 'one true X'.

Comment: Is that not just the etymology of _true_, rather than _one true_?

Comment: see my edit if you will.